# Spring saml not redirecting to success url after authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-saml

After successful user authentication I can see the response in my IDE console. But it is not redirecting to the success URL.
My application.properties file contains:
[image]

I am not getting any help from saml docs etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Complete logs with DEBUG level could help pinpoint this.